# Count how many users are there per each category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get user data, them get department value to array so I can group it and count how many users are part of the same department.

User table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();         
});
```

Department table:

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name');
});
```

Assignment table:

```
Schema::create('assignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->string('name');
     $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');   
     $table->unsignedInteger('department_id')->nullable();
     $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');             
});

public function setDepartment($users)
{
        $departmentArray = [];
        $users = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('assignments','assignments.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->leftJoin('departments','assignments.department_id','=','department.id')
            ->select('assignments.id as assignments',
                     'assignments.name as assignment_name',
                     'departments.id as dept_id',
                     'departments.name as dept_name',
                     'users.id as user_id',
                     'users.name as user_name'
                    )
            ->where('user_id','=',$users->id)
            ->get();

        foreach($users as $user) {
                $assignments = $user->assignments;
                $dept_id = $user->dept_id;

                $departmentArray[$user->dept_id] = $user->dept_name;

            }
            $users->department = $departmentArray;
            $users->dept_id = $dept_id;
        }
}
```

Then whenever I try to call this like:

```
public function index() {

    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $users = $this->setDepartment($users);
    return view('/users/list', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);

}
```

I receive

> "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object"

Comment: I want to clarify some parts, you want to get all the users under the same department right?

Comment: can you check which line causing this error?

Comment: @Miggy that's correct.

Comment: Do you have a relationship for these tables in your models? And if so, can you post them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'A department has many users through assignments'**

Documentation for hasManyThrough: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Departments Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Assignment');
}
```

**'Count how many users there are for each department'**

Departments controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $departments = Department::all();

    foreach($departments as $department)
    {
         // This line returns the number of users for the department
         // Use this however you please
         $department->users->count();
    }
}
```

Documentation for count() found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates

You can work out the reverse of the relationship if you need to go from users to department, but I would suggest looking into eloquent, it can be quite handy for queries such as these. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

**Edit:**

For access from user to department, this is one way of defining the relationships.

User Model:

```
// A user belongs to many departments through their assignments
public function departments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Department', 'App\Assignment');
}
```

This way you can access the departments of the user like so:

`$departments = $user->departments();`

And iterate through the `$departments`, accessing the `count()` as explained above.

Comment: Yes, I do need to go from users to departments. I tied the following:    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Assignment', 'App\Department');
    }    ; and then             $departments = Department::all();

            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                 // This line returns the number of users for the department
                 // Use this however you please
                 $user->department->count();

            } and it return only an empty array.

Comment: What is the relationship between users and departments from this side of the relationship? Because my code above is 'a department has many users through assignments', are you looking for 'a user belongs to many departments through assignments'?

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain the reverse, let me know if it needs anything else.